# $f$ is continuous, $f : X \to X$, $X$ compact, and $f$ has an $\epsilon$-fixed point for each $\epsilon > 0$. Show $f$ has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Problem: Let $f : X \to X$ be a map from a metric space to itself. A point $z \in X$ is a fixed point of $f$ if $f(z) = z$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. A point $w \in X$ is an $\epsilon$-fixed point of $f$ if $d(f(w),w)<\epsilon$. Prove: if $X$ is a compact metric space, $f: X \to X$ is a continuous function, and if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $f$ has an $\epsilon$-fixed point, then $f$ has a fixed point.

**Solution:** I started out by considering the sequence of points $w_n$, where $w_n$ is a $1/n$-fixed point for $f$. Now, since $f$ is continuous, if $w_n \to w$ in $X$, then we have

$$d(f(w),w) = d\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}f(w_n),\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0,$$

which implies that $w$ is a fixed point of $f$. However, I can't figure out how to show that $w_n \to w$ in $X$. I was trying to get it from the fact that $X$ is compact, which gives us that $X$ is complete and totally bounded, so every Cauchy sequence would converge, but I'm struggling to prove that $w_n$ is Cauchy. What I have so far is that

$$d(w_m,w_n) \le d(f(w_m),w_m) + d(f(w_m),f(w_n)) + d(f(w_n),w_n)$$
$$< 1/m + 1/n +d(f(w_n),f(w_m)).$$

Now, wlog, assume $m \ge n$, then

$$d(w_m,w_n) < 2/n + d(f(w_n),f(w_m))$$

So, if we fix $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $1/n < \epsilon/4$, and so

$$d(w_m,w_n) < \epsilon/2 + d(f(w_n),f(w_m)),$$

but then I've just made the problem into proving that $f(w_n)$ is Cauchy, which I don't know how I would do without knowing that $w_n$ is! I would appreciate a hint on where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: Every sequence in a compact set has a converging $______$.

Comment: Let $F(x)=d(x,f(x))$. Then $F$ is continuous. So $F(X)$ is compact.

Comment: Every compact metric space is sequentially compact.

Comment: @Did so, $w_{n_k} \to w_k$ for some subsequence of $w_n$. Then, I would take the limits of the subsequences instead of the full sequence to get that $d(f(w_k),w_k) = d\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}f(w_{n_k}),\lim_{k\to\infty}w_{n_k}\right) = 0$, and thus $w_k$ is a fixed point?

Comment: @gesa, exactly!

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for the confirmation! I never think to use sequential compactness, this was really helpful.